# Problems serializing DBML objects C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, serialization

I am trying to serialize some Linq objects using this code.

```
private byte[] GetSerializedObj(object o)
{
    try
    {
        DataContractSerializer formatter = new DataContractSerializer(o.GetType());
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        formatter.WriteObject(memStream, o);
        return memStream.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not serialize object", ex); 

    }
}
```

This works get on all objects. I marked the DBML as unidirectional for serialization. I have on my DBML type B which derives from type A. I can serialize each, but type C has a collection of type B on it. When I try to serialize a type C that has its B's loaded, it fails with a message like this.

> {"Type 'B' with data contract name
>   'B:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DLLNAME'
>   is not expected. Add any types not
>   known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types
>   passed to DataContractSerializer."}

Any ideas? Each goes by itself fine.

**Update 1**

I should also explain I know what the error means. I have used the knowntype attribute before. I have two issues here. One is that the DBML should generate the known attribute. The other is, why do the classes serialize when I create them themselves. For example,

```
A item = new B()
GetSerializedObj(item);
```

That works.

This does not.

```
C item = new C();
item.Bs.Add(new B());
GetSerializedObj(item);
```

**Update 2**

When you set the serialization to unidirectional, all classes get the datacontract attributes, and you also get datamemeber attributes on the members.

Comment: did you put the DataContract attribute on classes B and C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the exception message... apply the KnownTypeAttribute to class A :

```
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
class A
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I ended up just adding these to the class. I really thought it would get generated.